# "ADA.FLOAT_IO" is not a predefined library unit

Tags: ada

Why do i get this error?

> "ADA.FLOAT_IO" is not a predefined library unit

I've never written anything in ADA before, simply i have no idea what i'm doing. I use GNAT to compile.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_IO; use Ada.Float_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
use Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;

procedure MAIN is
   A,B,C:Float;
   W : Float;
   Re, Im:Float;
begin
   Put("Give A");Get(A);
   Put("Give B");Get(B);
   Put("Give C");Get(C);New_Line;
   if A=0.0 then
      Put_Line("It is not second degree polynomial");
   else
      W:=B*B - 4.0*A*C;
      Re:=B/(2.0*A); Im:=Sqrt(Abs(W))/(2.0*A);
      Put("dif = "); Put(W);New_Line;
      if W<0.0 then
         Put_Line("Complex ");
         Put("x1 = ");Put(-Re);Put(" -j ");Put(Im);Put(" ");
         Put("x2 = ");Put(-Re);Put(" +j ");Put(Im);New_Line;
      else
         Put_Line("Real");
         Put("x1 = ");Put(-Re-Im);Put(" ");
         Put("x2 = ");Put(-Re+Im);
      end if;
   end if;
end MAIN;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC `Float_IO` is a child of `Text_IO`: `Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO`. Furthermore, that's a generic package. I guess you want `Ada.Float_Text_IO`, which is defined as

```
package Ada.Float_Text_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Float);
```

Comment: Ok. Two questions. Where am i suppose to write it in my code? What is exactly happening in this line?

Comment: For your second question, see the [Wikibook article on generics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics). For the first, the  compiler provides `Ada.Float_Text_IO` ([ARM A10.9(32)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-9.html#p32)), so all _you_ have to do is replace `Ada.Float_IO` by `Ada.Float_Text_IO`.